# Make the bitmap get over ImageView borders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-xml

I'm running a rotation animation on a ImageView. The thing is the bitmap has been cut to fit exactly the ImageView. So when it rotate, it doesn't cover completely the ImageView as well as the screen.

This is what I want

[image]

And this is what happened

[image]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.LevelCompletedFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/vgBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3f5d68"
        android:alpha="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivStarburst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/star" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Run animation**

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
        **ivStarburst.startAnimation(shake);
```

---

**Edit:** **After following the solution by @deadfish the animation run correctly only when I open the fragment in onCreate() in MainActivity. If I trigger the fragment in onClick() method, it doesn't work.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MainFragment frgm = new MainFragment ();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, frgm).commit();
}
```

Comment: try `android:background="@drawable/star"` in your ImageView instead of `src` and also remove `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: I don't want the bitmap will be distorted. It makes the section look weird

Comment: Then set `scaleType:fitXY`

Comment: I tried all the different scale types, it doesn't work, dude

Comment: make the @drawable/star contained inside rotate drawable and change the its rotation property via ValueAnimator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did it but forget two things:

1. setting ImageView width and height as `match_layout` will match only to the parent's border. You must set custom dimenstion so when You center image, it will fill the whole view.
2. during image's rotation when the image reaches degree 45 we can notice the image doesn't fill the whole view. Why? Try put two rectangles on themself and then rotate one of them by 45 degree. Here is the result. According to definition of square, [it's diagonal value](https://ncalculators.com/area-volume/square-calculator.htm) is bigger than one of the sides of a square. So we must cover this.

[image]

Here is the solution.

1. we set custom dimension for ImageView basing on the longest side of the screen
2. we rewrite width to use diagonal width of square instead of single side

---

Most of the code is the same as Yours. I used fragment to show the sample.

//MainActivity part

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        this.<Button>findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

// Fragment part

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ImageView imageView = Objects.requireNonNull(view).findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Manually set image for ImageView
        setImageForView(imageView, R.drawable.star);

        // Turn ImageView to square where a = Max(Screen.width, Screen.height)
        changeDimensionToSquareForView(imageView);

        // Start rotations
        animateRotation(imageView);
    }

    private void changeDimensionToSquareForView(ImageView imageView) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        double maxWidth = Math.max(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);

        //calc diagonal line, x = a * sqrt(2)
        maxWidth = (maxWidth * (Math.sqrt(2)));

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) maxWidth, (int) maxWidth, Gravity.CENTER));
    }

    private void setImageForView(ImageView imageView, @DrawableRes int imageRes) {
        Context context = imageView.getContext();
        imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(imageRes, context.getTheme()));
    }

    // Call this method in onClick method
    public void animateRotation(ImageView imageView) {
        Context context = imageView.getContext();
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
        imageView.startAnimation(shake);
    }

}
```

Here is the layout of fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/star" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="15000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work on the first time I run the app, only work after I recreate activity like rotating screen

Comment: This sample executes animation on start activity, I didn't have any issue as You described.

Comment: Everything works if I start the fragment right away onCreate() in MainActivity. My issue happened when I start the fragment on method onClick() from a button in MainActivity

Comment: I have updated the code. onClick() didn't start animation because whole code was in listener which was listening to layout changes. Now it should should be OK.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I want to run animation at the same time when user starts fragment. I use onClick() in MainActivity to trigger the fragment. See my update

Comment: I have updated the code. Now every time You click the button, it will start the animation.

Comment: If works, I've seen what you did is just removing getViewTreeObserver(), could you explain in more detail to me?

Comment: getViewTreeObserver() was listening to layout changes, it was redundant